# SonarLint Command Line Tool - Add File/Folder Exceptions

Tags: android, command-line, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am using Sonarlint command line tool Version 1.0 for static code analysis in my Android project.It is analyzing ***src*** as well as ***gen*** folder.
I do not want gen folder to be analyzed.

As sonarlint has very less documentation, can anyone help me on "***How to add exceptions/Exclusions in sonarlint command line tool***".

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to specify which sources to analyze using a GLOB pattern. For example: `sonarlint --src '**/src/main/**'`.

Comment: It is saying, no files to analyze. I am in the project's root directory: sonarlint --src 'src/**'

Comment: can you please give me proper syntax for this?

Comment: could you try `'**/src/**'`  ?

Comment: Still the same result, Also I am on windows and using Eclipse based project structure

Comment: On windows you'll probably need to use something like `'**\\src\\**'`. I'm not on windows so can't test. You can check GLOB syntax in Java here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob

Comment: @DuarteMeneses Any Idea on how to add multiple folders for exclusion?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run the sonarlint in my windows command prompt of my module by the following glob syntax

```
cd myproject 

sonarlint --html-report reports/reports.html --src \**/main/java/**/*.java
```

my project folder is something like

```
myproject
+ src\main\java\...
+ src\test\java\...
+ src\main\resources
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

version 2.0 supports it `--exclude <glob pattern> GLOB pattern to exclude files`

`sonarlint --src '**/src/main/**' --exclude **/src/main/exclude_package**`

There is question on [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarlint/00tVM69TKYQ)